# get categorybuttons items caption under mouse in delphi

Tags: delphi, mouse, categories

how can I get caption of an item or a category when mouse is entering on them?
how can I get the current caption of an item or a category when right clicking on them?
I assigned a popup menu to categorybuttons. Now I need to obtain the current item or category captions and save them in variable. Because my popup menu has an item that by clicking on it it opens a new form so I want to use this variables values here.

Something like this works at click event :

```
Current_Items, Current_Category: String

procedure TForm1.CategoryButtons1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Current_Items := CategoryButtons1.CurrentCategory.Items
    [CategoryButtons1.SelectedItem.Index].Caption;
  Current_Category := CategoryButtons1.CurrentCategory.Caption;
end;
```

But I need to obtain them when right click.
Can someone helps me to do this?
Thank you...

Comment: To get the component that has triggered a popup menu to popup you can get by the `PopupComponent` property of the popup menu. And you can still pass those information as parameters to another form. I mean, in the popup menu item action event you can open your form passing the button information to the form whilst getting the current action source by `PopupComponent`.

Comment: @Victoria I think your suggestion will not work, because the categories and buttons are not separately identifiable on the popup level. The `popupcomponent` will be the whole `CategoryButtons1`

Comment: @Tom, I'm not sure about it (cannot test), but you should get the component that has triggered the popup menu to popup this way (no matter how it's arranged by a container). Of course such button must be enabled, otherwise you'd need to inspect which control is under the cursor. I'm not a friend of storing variables like that btw. I would create a method in that form and pass it as parameters.

Comment: @Victoria I repeat: the component that triggers the popup **is the `CategoryButtons1` component**. There are no published properties for the categories or the individual buttons, to which a popup could be attached.

Comment: @Tom, ok, I see, you are right. The `TCategoryButtons` component is a special container with no real subcomponents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

Use the OnHotButton event to prepare the `Current_Item` variable. That gives you the Item on which the mouse right button is clicked, but not the category.

Just note however that this does not select (activate) that particular button.

```
var
  Current_Items, Current_Category: String;

procedure TForm17.CategoryButtons1HotButton(Sender: TObject;
  const Button: TButtonItem);
begin
  if Button <> nil then
    Current_Items := Button.Caption;
end;
```

Then use `Current_Items` to identify which button is `hot` when you popup the menu.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But i tested this way before and it dos not retrieve thing that i want because when we use mouse down event the item under mouse pointer wont be selected. This is unlike on click event that item under mouse is selected...

Comment: Yes @M you are right, you could have said that you already tried, in your q. I'll try to think of something else.